# How does an early career researcher gain a high citation count?

Tags: publications

In my field of research (wireless networks ) I know of one researcher who is just 33 years old and has more than 1300 citations on Google-Scholar. How is this possible when he is so young? **What are the best methods to gain more academic citations and attention from other researchers for one's work?**

I think there are some parameters like this:

1. Contributing to open source project(s)
2. Working with other top researchers
3. Working on new field,  like new standard, etc .
4. Warm welcome to another researcher and willingness to help them.

Are these accurate? What other factors influence a high citation count at a relatively young age?

Comment: Citation counts vary dramatically between fields so this question isn't really answerable in its current state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While those kind of numbers are in the upper portion of the bell curve, they are not actually all that unusual.  Three likely scenarios for somebody to have 1000+ citations early in their career:

- One "super paper" that hit a hot topic with exactly the right idea at exactly the right time and did the scientific equivalent of going viral.
- Doing very good work as part of a highly productive group that a lot of people are paying attention to, and thus ending up with a number of well-cited papers.
- Leading an intellectual break-out into a new area of work, which many others become interested in.

It's great for somebody to have a good start to their career like this, but you shouldn't spend too much time worrying about it or comparing citation numbers: that way lies madness and brain-dead administrative metrics.

Comment: While this answer is 100% correct, it underestimates the fact that there are certain individuals that are so extremely and unusually talented that can produce a significant body of work within an inch of a time that the rest of us would require.

Comment: @Alexandros Sure, but that's much rarer than the cases I mention, I believe.

Comment: @jakebeal "Doing very good work as part of a highly productive group that a lot of people are paying attention to, and thus ending up with a number of well-cited papers." how many times tell you thanks for that advise

Comment: Another slightly self-congratulatory point of information: I am 36 and recently passed 1000 citations myself, and do not consider myself particularly unusual...